# how to remove the hashtag in URL of anythingslider,it works in FF,Chrome but not in IE browser?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, safari, hashtag, anythingslider

how to remove the hashtag e.g #&panel1-1  in the URL when using the anything slider ?
i have already set the

```
hashTags: false
```

and yet, it still appear on IE  and safari browsers

Answer (score 1):

problem solved,,,, it the memcache thing that made the hashtag is still there in the URL..
i cleared the memcache and everything worked just fine